# What is constant current LED driver output voltage?

Tags: led-driver

Does [Mean Well LLD-L](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=LDD-L&mw=glo) driver output same voltage as the input? Is it possible to limit the maximum output voltage for use as a lab bench supply? I want to use it to charge a lithium battery, if it is possible.

Comment: You should edit your hyperlink "this" to be the part number of the device you are referring to so that the reader might recognise the device without having to follow a link.

Answer (score 3):

The output voltage will be somwhere between 2V and 32V.  It is a constant current LED driver.  It tries to keep the current at a fixed value.  It keeps the current fixed by varying the output voltage so that the current remains constant.

- If you connect an LED with a forward voltage of 3V, the voltage will be just enough higher than 3V for 300mA to flow through the LED.
- If you connect eight 3V LEDs in series to it, the voltage will be just enough over 24V for 300mA to pass through the LEDs.

---

Charging a lithium battery with this power supply is probably a bad idea.

You need constant current and constant voltage during different parts of the charge cycle.  You also need a way to determine when the battery is charged.  Get any of that wrong, and you have a lithium battery that may go "bang" while charging or later when use.

Use a proper charger.